# How to use variable in mysql to get row data?

Tags: php

Ok so I am still kinda new to this I have a field called fields that when a new field is created that store the value in the database. What I want to do is bring the data back and name session arrays the name of the fields so that they auto generate.

Here's my code

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['fields'][$y]=$row['fields']; 
echo $_SESSION['fields'][$y]; 
echo""; 
$f= $_SESSION['fields'][$y]; 
echo $f; 
echo""; 
$_SESSION[$f][$y]=$row[$f]; 
echo $_SESSION[$f][1]; ; $y++;
```

Comment: When I echo $f it echos the field names that I want however it wont fetch the row

Comment: Where is the "MySQL"?

Comment: if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
   echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

 $result = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT * FROM customers');
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

Comment: Are you wanting to use the database in general to store session data? Take a look at [session_set_save_handler](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have the same problem .. I got solve it by :

using wordpress build in functions wpdb
dont use session_start since wordpress trigger session_start();

any question contact me : pimenteljchristopher@gmail.com

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "table_name";
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM $table_name" );

foreach ( $result as $print )   {
    echo $print->id;
    echo $print->fields1;
    echo $print->fields2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you just want to return the row from the database into a session, so you can use it later to construct HTML elements:

```
session_start();

$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'database');
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * from FIELDS where 1')):
    $stmt->execute();
    $fields = $stmt->get_result(); //so we can use fetch array and simplify this process
    while($row = $stmt->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)):  //foreach result set, return an associative array
        $_SESSION['fields'][] = $row; //push the array into your fields session
    endwhile;
    $stmt->close(); //close your statement
endif;
$myslqi->close(); //drop the mysqli connection, we're done

print_r($_SESSION['fields']); //lets see what fields looks like now

$ret = '';
foreach($_SESSION['fields'] as $row): //foreach row in sessions
    $ret .= '<div>'; //parent container for all fields in this row
    foreach($row as $idx => $field): //foreach field in the row## Heading ##
        $ret  .= '<span>'. $field . '</span>'; //create a div element to contain the field
    endforeach;
    $ret . = '</div>'; //close the parent container
endforeach;

echo $ret; //returned the constructed HTML for the fields
```

Comment: what I am trying to do is us the data from the field row to select data from other rows ie....  $fieldname=$row['fieldnames']; and then I want to call more data with something like $row=['$fieldname'];